# How to auto generate code for control property?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a custom control,the control has a collection of property.

I want to drag my control,auto add objects to the collection property of my control.

Like `TabControl.TabPages` auto code.When drag `TabControl` to a form,auto create 2 `TabPage` add in `TabControl.TabPages`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use custom designer like for TabControl:

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.TabControlDesigner, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
...
public class TabControl : Control
{
    ....
}
```

and the TabControlDesigner provides these two default tabs:

```
internal class TabControlDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
{
    public override void InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
    {
        base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);
        try
        {
            this.addingOnInitialize = true;
            this.OnAdd((object) this, EventArgs.Empty);
            this.OnAdd((object) this, EventArgs.Empty);
            ...
```